# .NET SqlCommand - finding Parameters in inline querys (Regex?)

Tags: .net, sql, regex, parameters

I've got a method that uses **sp_sproc_columns** to find all parameters that need to be send for a stored procedure.

My question is how can I do something similar for inline SQL querys?

I want to get a list of the parameters the query is expecting.

**Would the only way achieving this will be to use Regular expression? Any examples?**

---

***Example:***

```
sql = "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = @id AND name = @name"
```

I need to get a list that will contain **@id** and **@name**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to use a RegularExpression isn't too hard either - if that's the way you prefer to find your parameters:

```
   Regex r = new Regex(@"(?<Parameter>@\w*)", RegexOptions.Compiled);

   foreach (Match m in r.Matches(sqlStatement))
   {
      if(m.Success)
      {
         string parameterName = m.Value;
      }
   }
```

However, this is only going to give you the parameter **names** - it can't possibly guess or determine the parameter type or any of the other parameter metadata - so in the end, this might be a quick, but probably also "dirty" way to do it.

Marc

Comment: Why is it dirty? I've got a strongly typed object with all the values I'll need, and every member will have an attribute that will describe it's DB type. Does it sound dirty?  Is it really a bad practice?

Comment: Well, you can only extract the names of the parameters, and as Marc Gravell rightfully pointed out, this simplistic Regex can be fooled by simple edge cases - but if it's good enough for most of your cases, enjoy! ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you would have to fully parse the SQL. It might be more complex than you expect, especially if your SQL is rude enough to contain things like:

- internally executing a stored procedure using named parameters; for example `EXEC MyProc @foo = @localArg` - here only `@localArg` is needed for your query
- having a string with `'some text @foo more text'` in it -perhaps due to calling `sp_ExecuteSQL` (`@foo` is not part of your query)

Comment: I've got a solution for stored procedures, I use sp_sproc_columns.
This should be a solution for simple inline query's only.

Comment: Lets hope the "simple query" doesn't do an EXEC, then... ;-p

Comment: So is this really just a regular expression issue? What should be the expression?

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code to get the Parameters Name in Inline queries:

```
  Dim SQL As String =  "SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE id = @id AND name = @name"

  Dim arr = SQL.Split(" "c)
  For Each str As String In arr
    If str.StartsWith("@") Then
      MessageBox.Show(str)
    End If
  Next
```

Comment: Splitting by space isn't robust; you could have "(@foo", ",@foo","+@foo", etc

Comment: yes you are right, it's not easy to collect all the cases and put it in the split char array.

Comment: @ could also legimately appear as part of a string in the SQL

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the SQL Server provider, and if you are using a stored procedure, you can use the [`SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommandbuilder.deriveparameters.aspx).

For other cases, I've always found that the best way, if your commands are at least constant, is to use the Designer support in Visual Studio. Either create a strongly-typed `DataSet` and add a query, or do it the old fashioned way and drag a `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` onto a design surface. In either case, when you configure the CommandText to be a statement with parameters, the Designer will ask you if you want the `Parameters` collection filled in. The result is that it will have generated the code to create a SqlCommand with the parameters collection already created. All you'll need to do is set the parameter values, and you're all set.